# How to make a sentence using multiple values from a dictionary?

Tags: python

Now I just started to study python.
I want to make a sentence which using multiple variables in a dictionary in a sentence.
Here is the dictionary I chose.

```
people = [
    {'name': 'bob', 'age': 20, 'score':{'math':90,'science':70}},
    {'name': 'carry', 'age': 38, 'score':{'math':40,'science':72}},
    {'name': 'smith', 'age': 28, 'score':{'math':80,'science':90}},
    {'name': 'john', 'age': 34, 'score':{'math':75,'science':100}}
]
```

I want to make a sentence describing carry's math test score.

Expected full sentence is:

> carry got 40 points in a math test.

To make the sentence, I put:

```
sentence = people[1]['name'] + ' got ' + people[1]['score']['science'] + ' points in a ' + people[1]['score'][0] + ' test.'

print(sentence)
```

It comes out with TypeError: can only concatenate srt (not "int") to str.

How can I fix the problem here?

carry got 40 points in a math test.

Comment: Add `str()` around the variables for the numbers or use f-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to convert int into Str for you to do perform concatenation.

But I'd suggest you to use the f strings for interpolation

```
sentence = f'{people[1]["name"]}  got {people[1]["score"]["math"]} points in a {list(people[1]["score"])[0]}  test.'

print(sentence)
```

Output:

> carry  got 40 points in a math  test.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using f-strings, also known as Literal String Interpolation:

```py
sentence = f'{people[1]['name']} got {people[1]['score']['science']} points in a {people[1]['score'][0]} test.'
```

This way, you don't need to use `str()` arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = people[1]['name'] + ' got ' + str(people[1]['score']['science']) + ' points in a ' + str(people[1]['score']['math']) + ' test.'    
print(sentence)
```

You need to convert int to string so you can contact string. You were getting an error because you were adding string and int to form a string. `people[1]['score'][0]` was also giving an error as score contains a dictionary so I have accessed a `math` key and it is working now.

Comment: still error!! `KeyError: 0`

Comment: I have edited it, it should work now.

Comment: `people[1]['score'][0]` was also giving an error as `score` contains a dictionary so I have accessed a `math` key and it is working now

Comment: please see the above two answers and their output!! your output is not matching the desired output..!

Comment: I have updated it. Output `'carry got 72 points in a 40 test.'`

Comment: desired output man is `carry got 40 points in a math test.`..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250783/discussion-between-yash-mehta-and-ikram-khan-niazi).

Answer (score 0):

```
for person in people:  #Loop on people

    print(str(person['name']) + ' of age-' + str(person['age']) + ' got score of ' + str(person['score']['math']) + ' in math test.\n')
```

> Output:-
>
> bob of age-20 got score of 90 in math test.
>
> carry of age-38 got score of 40 in math test.
>
> smith of age-28 got score of 80 in math test.
>
> john of age-34 got score of 75 in math test.